# How do pilots cope with pressurization changes?

Tags: medical

I have tried

- drinking a glass of water
- yawning
- plugging my nostrils and pushing air

but none of these seem to work - I still have a distinct pain in my upper sinus cavities when changing pressure in an airplane. I have the same pain underwater.

Do some pilots have this problem, and do they have a remedy?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should also try asking this in a diving forum. Equalizing is usually a much bigger issue for divers than pilots, so you're likely to get a good response there. [This](http://www.diversalertnetwork.org/medical/faq/Instructions_for_Equalizing_Ears_and_Sinuses) is a good place to start, DAN is a great resource for dive medical information and support. And see [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/10043/62) too.

Comment: (Amateur) advanced diver here.  You should consult a doctor.  Not being to equalise normally. for example with the [Valsalva manoeuvre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_maneuver) may indicate an underlying condition.

Comment: I know that I am more sensitive to pressure changes when I have a cold. A closed [eustachian tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustachian_tube) makes all the difference. What helps me most is moving my jawbone left and right - this opens up the tube and helps to equalize pressure.

Comment: Over time you just get used to it.  But you can do the valsalva trick and plug your nose and blow. Chewing gum and talking help too.

Comment: Me, I stay low.  Under 5000 AGL if I can help it, and I never, ever fly commercial anymore, those commercial jets yank the air pressure all over the place way too fast.

Comment: @Pondlife: Damn, we don't have a Diving Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Sean Well, [sort of](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scuba-diving) but not really :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a chance you suffer from [aerosinusitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosinusitis) but you should consult a physician to obtain a proper diagnosis (Disclaimer: I am NOT a doctor). For what its worth commercial planes are pressurized generally to about the [pressure you would see at 8000 ft.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_pressurization#Cabin_altitude) this equates to about .75 Atm. In the reverse case 33ft underwater already has you at 2 Atm.

When I fly (generally unpressurized) I usually chew gum which i find helps.

Comment: I do this also for high altitude climbing. I find it very useful at adjustments to pressure.